# How to log messages to Azure servicebus queue & read from the it using nlog?

Tags: wcf, nlog, azure-servicebus-queues

How can I log messages to a Azure Service Bus Queue and read messages from it in application.

Comment: See [NLog.Extensions.AzureServiceBus](https://github.com/JDetmar/NLog.Extensions.AzureStorage/blob/master/src/NLog.Extensions.AzureServiceBus/README.md) or [NLog.Extensions.AzureQueueStorage](https://github.com/JDetmar/NLog.Extensions.AzureStorage/blob/master/src/NLog.Extensions.AzureQueueStorage/README.md) or [NLog.Extensions.AzureEventHub](https://github.com/JDetmar/NLog.Extensions.AzureStorage/blob/master/src/NLog.Extensions.AzureEventHub/README.md)

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a guide [how to use queues in .net](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-dotnet-how-to-use-queues/).

Focus on "How to send messages to a queue" and "How to receive messages from a queue".

The main idea of this is to create a `QueueClient` object using a connection string, create a `BrokeredMessage` and then send it to the queue.

For receiving the message, I believe that you will have a service (lets say a worker role for example) peeking messages from that queue.
There you will need to create a client and add a callback to handle the received messages. When you receive the message you can log it using Nlog.